# Simple relational database planning suggestions

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I'm creating a simple application, where a user logs in via an OAuth system, and I store their user ID in a session.

My database has 3 tables: User, Group & Page

- A user can be in many groups
- A group can have many users
- A page can have many groups

So essentially in my settings area:

- A user can be assigned to groups
- The groups can be added to pages to allow access

I can then use the user's ID, to find what group(s) they are in, and then select the page IDs they have access to.  However this method seems very long winded and I think will involve quite a few loops (also, I think I'd then be getting many of the same page ID's back?).

A sketch up of my explanation:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9G6n.png

I do have a feeling there is a better way to accomplish this though - using one "pivot" table, and 3 tables... Something like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu8KV.jpg

If someone could give some insight into what would be best, and also whether my relationships (M-t-M) are correct, that'd be awesome.

FYI: Building it on Laravel 4

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've done it (in your first diagram) is better, for the way you've stated your problem.

Users belong to groups and pages permissions are mapped to groups. There is no direct relationship between pages and users (i.e. you can't assign a permission to access a page directly to a user, but only to a group the user belongs to). If the above is a correct description of what you're trying to do, the first diagram is the most normalized way to design your DB.

With your second diagram, you would be able to do insert in your DB relationships that don't make sense. For instance your Link table could contain these rows

```
[user.id=1, group.id=1, page.id=1] 
[user.id=1, group.id=2, page.id=2]
[user.id=2, group.id=2, page.id=1]
```

Now, with these rows, group 2 can access both page 1 and page 2 (rows 2 and 3). But user 2 belongs to group 2 and can only access page 1 (row 3).
You can still make this work, but you would need to control from your application that all the rows in Link make sense.

Comment: Yes this makes sense now, I didn't think about the whole situation that you described so will stick with the normalized approach. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Usually [Fourth Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_normal_form) is meant to prevent you from storing multiple many-to-many relationships in a single intersection table.

In this case, you grant access to a page to a group, not to a user.  So I wouldn't store the reference to the page in the same table that notes user membership in the groups.

Say for example you had 1000 users in a group, and that group has access to 1 page.  But in your second design, you'd have to store the group's access to the page on 1000 rows.

Answer (score 1):

The first approach (with 5 tables) is more normalized. I'd suggest sticking with that unless you have a specific reason to denormalize.

The following SQL will get all the distinct page ids for a given user:

```
select DISTINCT GP.page_id
from GroupUser GU
join GroupPage GP on GU.group_id = GP.group_id 
where GU.user_id = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

The three way relationship table means something completely different than two two way relationship tables because it joins three entities together.

If you want to describe that `user1` is member of `group1` you use this in the first two-way table:

```
user     group
user1    group1
```

But extending with another field and a page changes the meaning:

```
user     group    page
user1    group1   page1
```

This creates an association not only between `user1` and `group1`, `group1` and `page1`, but also `user1` and `page1`.

At the same time, you can have really odd situations like this:

```
user     group    page
user1    group1   page1
user1    group1   page2
user1    group2   page1
```

Note that in this example, there is no row with `user1 group2 page2`. In other words, `user1` is related to `page1` only through `group2` and `user1` is only related to `group2` through(?!?) `page1`. I hope it is clear that this doesn't match what you described in the first place.

So my take is go with the two relationship tables in the first example.